# Prime number in a given range in python, problem with range(),

Tags: python, for-loop, range, primes

This program prints prime no between 1-20, i have tried to grasp the working of(for loop,range & else associated with for) in this program

```
def isPrime(num):
    for i in range(2,num):
        if num%i==0:
            return False
        #else:
            #return True
    else:
        return True

#below is driver program        
for i in range(1, 20):
    if isPrime(i + 1):
        print(i + 1, end="\n")
print()
```

1.in this program put num//2 instead of num in `range()` result is diff (prints 4 as prime)why?

2. when 2 is sent to `isprime()`, it doesn't even enter for loop,it is not being checked by if conditions but outputs 2 as a prime by the else block associated with for. why?how? 
   **i think  because of `range(2,num)`,2 is passed as num.**

Can someone Explain??

Comment: What didn't you understand from the `range` documentation?  What describe is just what the docs tell you will happen.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that `range(2,n)` is all numbers 2, 3, ..., n-1. So change your `for` loop to:

```
for i in range(2,num+1):
```

As is, when 2 is passed in, the range will be empty.